# ffmpeg merge two commands

Tags: command-line, video, ffmpeg, syntax

I have two ffmpeg commands which work as expected- 
1: a simple recode, removes sound

> ffmpeg -report -i $MP4FILE -an -vf hflip -movflags faststart $OUTPUTFILE.mp4 -nostdin

2: an overlay with an image for branding:

> ffmpeg -i $MP4FILE   -i OverlayTest.png  -filter_complex "overlay=0:0" TestBrandVid2.mp4

I need to combine these commands into a single line (in a bash script), but I am having trouble with the syntax (and with understanding the syntax from the ffmpeg documentation...) - the following doesn't work:

> ffmpeg  -i $MP4FILE -an  -movflags faststart -i OverlayTest.png -filter_complex "[0:v]hflip[a];[a][1:v]overlay=0:0[out]” -map “[out]”   TestBrandVid2.mp4 -nostdin

Can you help? Thanks!

Added: console output is a prompt only - I have no idea what it wants, though...:

> smarter$ ffmpeg  -i 447G.mp4 -an  -movflags faststart -i VideoBrandingOverlay.png -filter_complex "[0:v]hflip[a];[a][1:v]overlay=0:0[out]” -map “[out]”   testoutcome.mp4 -nostdin
>   `>`
>   >

SORTED!  stripped everything out and added back one at a time - it was the position of the "-an -movflags" options. This works:

> ffmpeg -i 447G.mp4 -i VideoBrandingOverlay.png -filter_complex "[0:v]hflip[a];[a][1:v]overlay=0:0" -an -movflags faststart testout.mp4 -nostdin

Comment: Combined cmd looks ok. Paste the console output.

Comment: Add `-report` to your cmd. A logfile will be generated. Paste that here.